# Tengo problemas para visualizar mi plantilla de html cuando envío la función mail con PHP

Tags: php, gmail, mail

Estoy intentado enviar un email con plantilla usando la función *mail* de PHP, pero por mas que le busque la lógica siempre me envía el email sin la plantilla, solo con el código hecho un desastre. Mejor dicho no me lee el código y me lo lanza al pelo por gmail.
Pero algo curioso es que cuando uso **mailinator** me funciona, me lanza la plantilla de correo muy bien.
**Así es como me sale el corro por gmail:**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Este es código de la plantilla con la función mail:**

```
$mensaje = "<body style='margin: 0; padding: 0;'>
    <table border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' width='100%'> 
        <tr>
            <td style='padding: 10px 0 30px 0;'>
                <table align='center' border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' width='600' style='border: 1px solid #cccccc; border-collapse: collapse;'>
                    <tr>
                        <td align='center' bgcolor='#70bbd9' style='padding: 40px 0 30px 0; color: #153643; font-size: 28px; font-weight: bold; font-family: Arial, sans-serif;'>
                            <img src='https://i.ibb.co/v1SpB08/h1.gif' alt='Imagen de portada' width='300' height='230' style='display: block;' />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td bgcolor='#ffffff' style='padding: 40px 30px 40px 30px;'>
                            <table border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' width='100%'>
                                <tr>
                                    <td style='color: #153643; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 24px;'>
                                        <b style='color: #4caf50'>¡Ya eres parte de nuestra comunidad !</b>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td style='padding: 20px 0 30px 0; color: #153643; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; line-height: 20px;'>
                                        Ya te has registrado. ¿Ahora que sigue ? pues ahora solo debes publicar tus productos en Bomgos y conseguir cliente potenciales con los cuales puedes hacer crecer tu negocio.
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <table border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' width='100%'>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td width='260' valign='top'>
                                                    <table border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' width='100%'>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td>
                                                                <img src='https://i.ibb.co/M69gMQt/left.gif' alt='Publica tus productos en Bomgos' width='100%' height='140' style='display: block;' />
                                                            </td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td style='padding: 25px 0 0 0; color: #153643; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; line-height: 20px;'>
                                                                Publica tus productos en Bomgos y aprovecha en gran auge que estan teniendo las ventas por Internet, tu tambien lo puedes hacer y con Bomgos es muy fácil vender y ganar dinero, recuerda que Bomgos es totalmente gratis y que nunca te cobrara por hacerte vender tus productos.
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </table>
                                                </td>
                                                <td style='font-size: 0; line-height: 0;' width='20'>
                                                    &nbsp;
                                                </td>
                                                <td width='260' valign='top'>
                                                    <table border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' width='100%'>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td>
                                                                <img src='https://i.ibb.co/8b57Kb6/right.gif' alt='Compra productos con Bomgos' width='100%' height='140' style='display: block;' />
                                                            </td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td style='padding: 25px 0 0 0; color: #153643; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; line-height: 20px;'>
                                                                Tambie puedes comprar todos los productos que quieras en Bomgos, solo tienes que buscar el productos y entrar en contacto con el vendedor del productos. Recuerda leer los comentarios del producto y en caso de realizar una comprar satisfactoriamente, dejar una critica en el perfil del vendedor del producto. 
                                                            </td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </table>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td bgcolor='#ee4c50' style='padding: 30px 30px 30px 30px;'>
                            <table border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' width='100%'>
                                <tr>
                                    <td style='color: #ffffff; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px;' width='75%'>
                                        &reg; Bomgos 2020<br/>
                                        <a href='#' style='color: #ffffff;'><font color='#ffffff'>bomgos.com</font></a> Visitanos
                                    </td>
                                    <td align='right' width='25%'>
                                        <table border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td style='font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold;'>
                                                    <a href='https://twitter.com/Bomgos1' style='color: #ffffff;'>
                                                        <img src='https://i.ibb.co/n1xLk03/tw.gif' alt='Twitter' width='38' height='38' style='display: block;' border='0' />
                                                    </a>
                                                </td>
                                                <td style='font-size: 0; line-height: 0;' width='20'>&nbsp;</td>
                                                <td style='font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold;'>
                                                    <a href='https://www.facebook.com/Bomgos-101693671642850/' style='color: #ffffff;'>
                                                        <img src='https://i.ibb.co/yp6ZN3c/fb.gif' alt='Facebook' width='38' height='38' style='display: block;' border='0' />
                                                    </a>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>";

mail($email, $asunto, $mensaje);
```

**Esta es la plantilla como debería de verse en gmail:**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si necesitan mas información, solo déjenlo saber. Un saludo

Comment: ¿Es posible que debas agregar el tag html y el tag head al contenido?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Para enviar un correo HTML, debe establecerse la cabecera Content-type

```php
$cabeceras .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
```

> ### **Ejemplo #4 Envío de un correo HTML**
>
> Es posible también enviar correos `HTML` con `mail()`.
>
> ```
> <?php
> // Varios destinatarios
> $para  = 'aidan@example.com' . ', '; // atención a la coma
> $para .= 'wez@example.com';
>
> // título
> $título = 'Recordatorio de cumpleaños para Agosto';
>
> // mensaje
> $mensaje = '
> <html>
> <head>
>   <title>Recordatorio de cumpleaños para Agosto</title>
> </head>
> <body>
>   <p>¡Estos son los cumpleaños para Agosto!</p>
>   <table>
>     <tr>
>       <th>Quien</th><th>Día</th><th>Mes</th><th>Año</th>
>     </tr>
>     <tr>
>       <td>Joe</td><td>3</td><td>Agosto</td><td>1970</td>
>     </tr>
>     <tr>
>       <td>Sally</td><td>17</td><td>Agosto</td><td>1973</td>
>     </tr>
>   </table>
> </body>
> </html>
> ';
>
> // Para enviar un correo HTML, debe establecerse la cabecera Content-type
> $cabeceras  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
> $cabeceras .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
>
> // Cabeceras adicionales
> $cabeceras .= 'To: Mary <mary@example.com>, Kelly <kelly@example.com>' . "\r\n";
> $cabeceras .= 'From: Recordatorio <cumples@example.com>' . "\r\n";
> $cabeceras .= 'Cc: birthdayarchive@example.com' . "\r\n";
> $cabeceras .= 'Bcc: birthdaycheck@example.com' . "\r\n";
>
> // Enviarlo
> mail($para, $título, $mensaje, $cabeceras);
> ?>
> ```
>
> **Nota:**
>
> Si la intención es enviar `HTML` u otro tipo de correo complejo, es recomendable usar el paquete `PEAR » PEAR::Mail_Mime`.
>
> [PHP MAIL](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.mail.php)